# JavaFX : How to dynamically change the controller in the same fxml file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Experts! I just want to use a button for the couple of controllers so that I want to make my code be short. In bottom of a boderpane, I made buttons for changing the view of center of the borderpane, and once the next button clicked, it's changed another view that located in the center of the borderpane. However, if I click the check button, I expected that the massage for displayMassageLabel would come up, but it makes an error.. Is there anyone to  solve this problem..?
Here are sample codes I simply made below.

ChangeControllerTestMain.java

```
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author James
 */
public class ChangeControllerTestMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.MainController">
   <bottom>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="backButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBackButtonAction" text="&lt;Back" />
            <Button fx:id="checkButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCheckButtonAction" text="Check" />
            <Button fx:id="nextButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNextButtonAction" text="Next&gt;" />
         </children></HBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

MainColtroller.java

```
package javafxapplication2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

/**
 *
 * @author James
 */
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    private Label displayMassageLabel;

    @FXML
    private Button backButton;
    @FXML
    private Button checkButton;
    @FXML
    private Button nextButton;

    private int currentMenuNum;
    private String currentViewerPath;
    private String pathList[] = {"StartDisplay.fxml", "Menu1Display.fxml", "Menu2Display.fxml", "Menu3Display.fxml"};

    private Menu1DisplayController menu1DisplayController = new Menu1DisplayController();
    private Menu2DisplayController menu2DisplayController = new Menu2DisplayController();
    private Menu3DisplayController menu3DisplayController = new Menu3DisplayController();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        currentMenuNum = 0;
        currentViewerPath = pathList[currentMenuNum];
        System.out.println(currentViewerPath);
        setControlItems(currentViewerPath, currentMenuNum);
    }

    private void setControlItems(String path, int currentMenuNum) {
        //Display setting for menu
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(path));
            anchorPane = fxmlLoader.load();
            //connectionViewerController = (ConnectionViewerController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace().toString());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        borderPane.setCenter(anchorPane);

        if (currentMenuNum == 1) {
            menu1DisplayController = (Menu1DisplayController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        } else if (currentMenuNum == 2) {
            menu2DisplayController = (Menu2DisplayController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        } else if (currentMenuNum == 3) {
            menu3DisplayController = (Menu3DisplayController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        }
    }

    private String getCurrentViewerPath(int currentMenuNum) {
        currentViewerPath = pathList[currentMenuNum];
        return currentViewerPath;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBackButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if (currentMenuNum == 0) {
            return;
        }
        currentMenuNum = currentMenuNum - 1;
        currentViewerPath = getCurrentViewerPath(currentMenuNum);
        setControlItems(currentViewerPath, currentMenuNum);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleNextButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        currentMenuNum = currentMenuNum + 1;
        currentViewerPath = getCurrentViewerPath(currentMenuNum);
        setControlItems(currentViewerPath, currentMenuNum);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleCheckButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        displayMassageLabel.setText("Welcome Menu " + currentMenuNum);
    }
}
```

StartDisplay.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="361.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Display Message" />
            <Label text="Start Display" />
            <Label fx:id="displayMassageLabel" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Menu1DisplayController.java

```
package javafxapplication2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author James
 */
public class Menu1DisplayController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label displayMassageLabel;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }   

    @FXML
    private void handleCheckButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        displayMassageLabel.setText("Welcome Menu 1");
    }

}
```

Menu1Display.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.Menu1DisplayController">
   <children>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="361.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Display Message" />
            <Label text="Current Menu is 1" />
            <Label fx:id="displayMassageLabel" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXML files and controllers  for menu2 and 3 are the same as menu 1's.
pleas help me.

These are errors..

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$105/472212858.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafxapplication2.MainController.handleCheckButtonAction(MainController.java:101)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: Could it be the missing @FXML Tag above the displayMessageLabel?

Comment: @FXML
    private Label displayMassageLabel; I already added that before. But it's still not working

Comment: The problem is the way you initialize the label. Its declared in all fxml files except the Main.fxml but this is the one where you want to reference it but it is null and so the error. Either you put the label into Main.fxml or you have to declare a setMessageLabel function in all other controller which you can then call from MainController and pass the value.

Comment: Then, should I add more logics to decide which controller take  the value passed from maincontroller? such as "if conditions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function

```
public void setDisplayMessageLabel(String message){
     displayMassageLabel.setText(message);
}
```

to all Menu1DisplayControllers (Menu1,Menu2,...).
Know you could call this function from your MainContorller like

```
@FXML
private void handleCheckButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
   if (currentMenuNum == 1) {
        menu1DisplayController.setDisplayMassageLabel("Welcome Menu " + currentMenuNum;
    } else if (currentMenuNum == 2) {
        menu2DisplayController.setDisplayMassageLabel("Welcome Menu " + currentMenuNum;
    } else if (currentMenuNum == 3) {
        menu3DisplayController.setDisplayMassageLabel("Welcome Menu " + currentMenuNum;
    }

}
```